# When i click the Add button to the gridview then the following code add the double record

Tags: c#

When I click the Add button to the grid view then the following code add the double record...

```
int drow;

private void btn_poyeeNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drow = Dg.Rows.Add();
    Dg.Rows[drow].Cells[0].Value = txtPayee.Text;
}

public void showdatainGridview()
{
    try 
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(HrGlobal.DbCon);
        query = "select payee_name from Tbl_payee";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        drow = 0;
        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                drow = Dg.Rows.Add();
                Dg.Rows[drow].Cells[0].Value = row["payee_name"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void PayeeBook_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showdatainGridview();
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Set a breakpoint at beginig of `btn_poyeeNew_Click` method and check if it called twice

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Also : __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Well you do have two lines with `drow = Dg.Rows.Add();`. Why?

Comment: Ur insert should insert the data into the database. And load will load the data from the database